# <input/> inside <label> not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, forms

my current markup is as follows:

```
<li class="multi_answer"> 
    <label for="checkbox2">
        <div class="multi_answer_box">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" class="multi_box" />
        </div>
        <div class="multi_answer_text">Checkbox Label</div>
    </label>
</li>
```

works great in everything **BUT** firefox.

after inspecting the markup, it's reading it as...

```
<li class="multi_answer">
    <label for="checkbox1"> </label>
    <div class="multi_answer_box">
        <input id="checkbox1" class="multi_box" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    </div>
    <div class="multi_answer_text"> Increased counseling staff </div>
</li>
```

ideas why FF would be interpreting it this way?

I also am using this css

```
.multi_answer label:hover {
    background:#DDD;
}

.multi_answer_box input {
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    float:left;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
}

.multi_answer label {
    overflow: auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:auto;
    margin:10px;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background:#CCC;
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NhD3r/1/  <---- **working example**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because `label` must contain [inline elements only](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1), and not block elements like `div`.

***SOLUTION***

replacing all `div`'s with `span`'s retained intended styling and function while complying with above stated rule.

```
<li class="multi_answer"> 
    <label for="checkbox2">
        <span class="multi_answer_box">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" class="multi_box" />
        </span>
        <span class="multi_answer_text">Checkbox Label</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Good thought, but I have changed this in CSS, sorry, I'll add that to the question.

Comment: You cannot make a block element an inline element by CSS. The HTML parser "corrects" your input before even considering CSS.

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with this, `<label>` cannot contain block level elements (by specs).

Comment: well specs are great and all, but **every** other browser supports it, including the newer versions of FF as you pointed out. Looks like it's becoming a de facto spec if you ask me.

Comment: @jondavidjohn - It's not de facto any more. The parser spec for HTML5 describes how to handle it. Firefox 3 did not support the HTML5 parser algorithm, and it's error recovery behaviour was unusual when handling block level elements inside inline level ones.

Comment: @jondavidjohn - HTML5 **standardized** it. Before, you were at the mercy of whatever error recovery the browsers happened to have in place. It's still an error in HTML5, it's just that what happens to recover from it is the same across all HTML5 compliant browsers.

Comment: I disagree that inline elements cannot be used as block level elements. They can but it's not good practice to do so. Take for example a popular site, www.meetup.com, their navigation menu at the top has span tags which are set to display:block in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your problem, I'm using FF6, anyway, you should try to validate your HTML and see if there's anything that may cause FF to behave the way it does. Also try clearing you cache (you can never know...)

Answer (score 0):

You can reorganize the HTML structure to be valid and follow the spec and still get the effect you want.

```
<li class="multi_answer">
    <div class="multi_answer_box">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" class="multi_box" />
        <label for="checkbox3">Did some additional important stuff and things,
               with a description that's long enough to wrap</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NhD3r/2/).

I made these changes and tested using Firefox 3.6.12 on Linux.